# Java - Convertir archivos en línea de comandos con LibreOffice - Ejecutar desde proceso hijo

Tags: java

Se me solicita crear un programa en Java que convierta un archivo .odt a pdf,usando LibreOffice en la línea de comandos. Se pide que la clase padre Conversor pase como argumento a la clase hija Doc2Pdf el comando para que sea ésta la que lo ejecute.

A modo de prueba, con el siguiente código logro que el proceso padre ejecute el comando, y el archivo, que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto, se convierte y crea correctamente en la carpeta pdf, también en la raíz:

```
public class U2A15_Conversor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program 
        Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.exe\" --convert-to pdf --outdir ./pdf 
        documento.odt");
        
        Process p = pb.start();
            
        p.waitFor();
            
        if(p.exitValue() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Archivo pdf generado correctamente");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error, no se ha generado el pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Como digo, este código de prueba, que no crea un proceso hijo sino que se ejecuta directamente, funciona bien.
Sin embargo, al crear el proceso hijo, pasarle el comando como argumento y ejecutarlo, el archivo no se crea, aunque también parece terminar con código 0, puesto que me indica que sí se ha creado:

```
public class U2A15_Conversor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String comando = "java psp.actividades.U2A15_Doc2Pdf \"C:\\Program 
        Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.exe\" --convert-to pdf --outdir ./pdf 
        documento.odt";

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(comando.split("\\s"));
        pb.directory(new File("build/classes"));

        Process p = pb.start();
            
        p.waitFor();
            
        if(p.exitValue() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Archivo pdf generado correctamente");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error, no se ha generado el pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

No logro identificar porqué no se está creando el archivo, puesto que lo único que cambia entre un código y otro es simplemente la clase que lo lanza.
Pienso que tal vez sea algo relacionado con pb.directory, es decir, que no estoy indicando correctamente dónde se encuentra el archivo, pero también supongo que el programa terminaría con código diferente a 0 en ese caso.

Edito: Agrego el código de la clase hija, que es quien debe ejecutar el comando. Originalmente la tenía vacía, porque creí que simplemente recibía los argumentos y los ejecutaba. Ahora he incluido a su vez en ella la creación de otro proceso, utilizando los argumentos que recibe, pero el resultado es el mismo:

```
public class U2A15_Doc2Pdf 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin ver la clase U2A15_Doc2Pdf no sabría decirte, parece que el fallo está ahí

Comment: Agregué el contenido de la segunda clase.

Comment: ¿Por qué otro proceso java en lugar de -simplemente- usar/importar la clase `psp.actividades.U2A15_Doc2Pdf`? ¿No hay dependencias y/o estás seguro que los .class están en el directorio apropiado? ya que no se ve que asignes un classpath.